# MANAGED_CLASS_MAPPING_ERROR: for 'class java.util.Comparators$NaturalOrderComparator'

Tags: javers

I am using Javers 2.9.2. When comparing two object getting this exception- MANAGED_CLASS_MAPPING_ERROR: given javaClass 'class java.util.Comparators$NaturalOrderComparator' is mapped to PrimitiveType, expected ManagedType

Comment: Start from getting the latest version of Javers

Comment: Did that but still it was failing. I had to replace Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder()) with Lamdba expression - (a,b) -> a.compareTo(b). 

I know this doesnt make sense but this is how it worked for my case.